# JQ: add the position in the json array to the element

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I actually receiving a json via API that contains several Arrays with different informations. Two of the Arrays are indirect linked. Array 1 contains an element that refers on the Array Position of an element in Array 2.
I am actually transforming that json to fits the requested requirements and to move it to a database. It is necessary to link the Information of both Arrays later in the database. So my idea is to add an element with the array position into the array 2.

Example:

original Array one:

```
{
  "country": [
    {
      "ContinentCode": "EU",
      "ContinentGroup": 1,
      "CountryCode": "DE",
      "CountryName": "Germany",
      "CurrencyIndex": 1
    },
    {
      "ContinentCode": "AM",
      "ContinentGroup": 2,
      "CountryCode": "CA",
      "CountryName": "Canada",
      "CurrencyIndex": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Array original two:

```
{
  "currency": [
    {
      "CODE": "EUR",
      "Name": "Euro"
    },
    {
      "Code": "CAD",
      "Name": "Canadian Dollar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Idea of the new array two:

```
{
  "currency": [
    {
      "CODE": "EUR",
      "Name": "Euro",
      "Position": 1
    },
    {
      "Code": "CAD",
      "Name": "Canadian Dollar",
      "Position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I use jq 1.5 under a Windows environment. I took a look in the manual but found no built in Feature to add Array Position into the element. Any ideas?

regards
Timo

Comment: Isn't there any common property in both the json. Which will act as a key to join the json like you want ?

Comment: Hi amit, no there is no common property beside the referance on the index Position in Array one. The currency Index number and Position will match as key

Comment: I don't know about jq but we can surely do it with the loop in which index of second json will work as position of json one. I can give you example in Javascript if you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the array index to the array elements in arr2.json, you could use `reduce`:

```
jq -f program.jq arr2.json
```

where program.jq contains:

```
.currency |= reduce range(0;length) as $i (.; .[$i].Position = 1+$i)
```

Or, assuming you're in a Windows environment:

```
jq ".currency |= reduce range(0;length) as $i (.; .[$i].Position = 1+$i)" arr2.json
```

Comment: Hi Peak, thanks for the solution offer. I tested the Code and got an error: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '$' or '[' or '{' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
 .Currency |= reduce range(0;length) as  (.; .[].Position = 1+)
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: 1. Try with program.jq.  2. Make sure there are no typos.

Comment: Hi Peak, okay if i run it with the program file it works. Funny. May be the $i is the problem. I invoke jq via powershell and on the powershell Windows the $i getting another collour independly of the the " or the '. Thanks alot for the solution. regards timo

Answer (score 0):

This is the example code of your requirement please run the code snippet and check your requirement

```js
var json1 ="{\"country\": [ { \"ContinentCode\": \"EU\", \"ContinentGroup\": 1, \"CountryCode\": \"DE\", \"CountryName\": \"Germany\", \"CurrencyIndex\" : 1}, { \"ContinentCode\": \"AM\", \"ContinentGroup\": 2, \"CountryCode\": \"CA\", \"CountryName\": \"Canada\", \"CurrencyIndex\" : 2}]}";
var json2 = "{\"currency\": [ { \"Code\": \"EUR\", \"Name\": \"Euro\" }, { \"Code\": \"CAD\", \"Name\": \"Canadian Dollar\" }]}";
        
var jsonParsed1 = JSON.parse(json1);
var jsonParsed2 = JSON.parse(json2);

var json3 = [];
for(var i=0;i<jsonParsed1.country.length;i++){
  var json3Object = {"Code":jsonParsed2.currency[i].Code,"Name":jsonParsed2.currency[i].Name,"Position":i+1};
  json3.push(json3Object);
}
console.log(json3);
```

Tell me if it Helps you

Comment: OP is not asking for a JS solution

Comment: Yes i know it is a kind of Example which may help him

Comment: You asked him if he wants a JS example but he did not respond yet. Why so hasty ?

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for the Code. A JS solution is not preffered but thanks for your time & Input. regards Timo